# how to get only some href attribute

Tags: php

I have this PHP code which I'm trying to extract some information but I stopped to href step:

```
$site = "http://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/countries";
$site_html = file_get_html($site);

$country_dirty = $site_html->getElementById('div_countries');

        foreach($country_dirty->find('img') as $link){

            $country = $link->alt;
            $link_country = "$site/$country";
            $link_country_html = file_get_html($link_country);

            $link_season = $link_country_html->getElementById('div_medals');

                foreach($link_season->find('a') as $season){


                    echo $link_year_season = $season->href . "\n";

                    //echo $link_season = strstr ($link_year_season,'summer') . "\n";

                }
            }
```

The variable $link_year_season gets me the following output:

```
/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/2012/
/olympics/athletes/ba/nesar-ahmad-bahawi-1.html
/olympics/athletes/ni/rohullah-nikpai-1.html
/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/2008/
/olympics/athletes/ba/nesar-ahmad-bahawi-1.html
/olympics/athletes/ni/rohullah-nikpai-1.html
/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/2004/
/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/1996/
/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/1988/
/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/1980/
/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/1972/
.....
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to get only this output:

```
/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/2012/
/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/2008/
/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/2004/
/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/1996/
/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/1988/
/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/1980/
/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/1972/
```

Comment: A quick way to do this would be to apply `preg_match` or `strpos` or something similar on the output that you are already getting.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this regex to check that the link starts with `/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/` then a number and a `/`.

```
foreach($link_season->find('a') as $season){
    if(preg_match('~^/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/\d+/~', $season->href)) {
         echo $link_year_season = $season->href . "\n";
         //echo $link_season = strstr ($link_year_season,'summer') . "\n";
    }
}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bZ1vP3/1

You could also pull the current year by capturing the number after summer (presuming that is a year, first regex just checks for number this one is stricter)..

```
foreach($link_season->find('a') as $season){
        if(preg_match('~^/olympics/countries/AFG/summer/(\d{4})/~', $season->href, $year)) {
             echo $link_year_season = $season->href . "\n";
             //echo $link_season = strstr ($link_year_season,'summer') . "\n";
             echo 'The year is ' . $year[1] . "\n";
        }
}
```

If the season also can vary you could do `(?:summer|winter)` which would allow for `summer` or `winter` to be the fourth directory.

Comment: If you wanted to allow for any country and any season, you could do `^\/olympics\/countries\/[A-Z]+\/(?:summer|winter)\/\d{4}\/`, presuming that summer and winter are the only seasons that the olympics occur ;)